# How do I generate rows of dates given a date and interval using Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle DB 18c: With the columns as JOBID, JOBSPEC, TRIGDT, GAPDAYS, I want to generate two more dates based on TRIGDT and GAPDAYS.

- The new columns showing the generated dates would be PRINTDT and COPYDT.
- For the first row, PRINTDT=TRIGDT and COPYDT=PRINTDT+GAPDAYS-1.
- For the next row, PRINTDT=(COPYDT from previous row)+1 and COPYDT=(new PRINTDT)+GAPDAYS-1.
- The rows keep generating until COPYDT cannot be greater than SYSDATE (current date)
- JOBID, JOBSPEC, TRIGDT, GAPDAYS remains the same in all repeating rows for each unique row in the input

I can do this in PLSQL with conditional loops, but it would be great if I can achieve this using a query. How can I achieve this using Oracle SQL query? Probably, a CONNECT BY clause, but I am not sure how I can approach it. Request your help.

Desired Output for the input data as noted below (SYSDATE=9/24/2023):
[image]

Input Data:

```
WITH
    tbl_print_schd
    AS
        (SELECT 'J101' AS JOBID, 'PRINT_DOC164' AS JOBSPEC, TO_DATE ( '06/29/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS TRIGDT, 15 AS GAPDAYS FROM SYS.DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'J2213' AS JOBID, 'PRINT_SYS_TBL22' AS JOBSPEC, TO_DATE ( '8/26/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS TRIGDT, 9 AS GAPDAYS FROM SYS.DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'J66' AS JOBID, 'ILLUM_STIG93' AS JOBSPEC, TO_DATE ( '9/10/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS TRIGDT, 11 AS GAPDAYS FROM SYS.DUAL)
SELECT JOBID
     , JOBSPEC
     , TRIGDT
     , GAPDAYS
  FROM tbl_print_schd;
```

**EDIT 1 (09/25/2023):**
Added another requirement I missed earlier:

- If TRIGDT is NULL, then it should not generate any rows. The output should not show this row.
- If the first row that contains COPYDT based on TRIGDT and GAPDAYS is greater than SYSDATE, then that row should be omitted from the output as well.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *row generator*, as you said. Here's one option which shows how to do it. Tweak it, if you think you should.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2      tbl_print_schd
  3      AS
  4          (SELECT 'J101' AS JOBID, 'PRINT_DOC164' AS JOBSPEC, TO_DATE ( '06/29/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS TRIGDT, 15 AS GAPDAYS FROM SYS.DUAL
  5           UNION
  6           SELECT 'J2213' AS JOBID, 'PRINT_SYS_TBL22' AS JOBSPEC, TO_DATE ( '8/26/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS TRIGDT, 9 AS GAPDAYS FROM SYS.DUAL
  7           UNION
  8           SELECT 'J66' AS JOBID, 'ILLUM_STIG93' AS JOBSPEC, TO_DATE ( '9/10/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AS TRIGDT, 11 AS GAPDAYS FROM SYS.DUAL)
```

Query:

```
  9  SELECT JOBID
 10       , JOBSPEC
 11       , TRIGDT
 12       , GAPDAYS,
 13       --
 14       trigdt + (gapdays * (column_value - 1))  as printdt,
 15       trigdt + (gapdays * (column_value - 1)) + gapdays - 1 as copydt
 16    FROM tbl_print_schd cross join
 17    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 18                        connect by level <= (sysdate - trigdt) / gapdays
 19                      ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

JOBID JOBSPEC         TRIGDT        GAPDAYS PRINTDT    COPYDT
----- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
J101  PRINT_DOC164    06/29/2023         15 06/29/2023 07/13/2023
J101  PRINT_DOC164    06/29/2023         15 07/14/2023 07/28/2023
J101  PRINT_DOC164    06/29/2023         15 07/29/2023 08/12/2023
J101  PRINT_DOC164    06/29/2023         15 08/13/2023 08/27/2023
J101  PRINT_DOC164    06/29/2023         15 08/28/2023 09/11/2023
J2213 PRINT_SYS_TBL22 08/26/2023          9 08/26/2023 09/03/2023
J2213 PRINT_SYS_TBL22 08/26/2023          9 09/04/2023 09/12/2023
J2213 PRINT_SYS_TBL22 08/26/2023          9 09/13/2023 09/21/2023
J66   ILLUM_STIG93    09/10/2023         11 09/10/2023 09/20/2023

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this worked beautifully, however, maybe with just one caveat. If there is just one row, i.e. for JOBID J66, if let's say, the TRIGDT is 9/20/2023, a row is still generated with COPYDT as 9/30/2023, which is greater than SYSDATE (As of this day of posting). Can we address it in the same query without making use of a subquery? The expectation would be that this row doesn't show up in the output even though it's present in source input data. Additionally, if TRIGDT is NULL, then it should not generate any rows as well. Sorry, I should have added it in my requirements.

Comment: You're welcome. For the rest of your comment, add (as the last, 20th line) this: `WHERE trigdt + (gapdays * (COLUMN_VALUE - 1)) + gapdays - 1 <= SYSDATE`

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time and effort to solve my problem :)

Comment: No problem; I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH rsq (jobid, jobspec, trigdt, gapdays, printdt, copydt) AS (
  SELECT jobid, jobspec, trigdt, gapdays, trigdt, trigdt + gapdays - 1
  FROM   tbl_print_schd
  WHERE  trigdt + gapdays - 1 <= SYSDATE
UNION ALL
  SELECT jobid, jobspec, trigdt, gapdays, printdt + gapdays, copydt + gapdays
  FROM   rsq
  WHERE  copydt + gapdays <= SYSDATE
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY jobid SET orderid
SELECT jobid, jobspec, trigdt, gapdays, printdt, copydt
FROM   rsq;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_print_schd (jobid, jobspec, trigdt, gapdays) AS
  SELECT 'J101',  'PRINT_DOC164',    DATE '2023-06-29', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J2213', 'PRINT_SYS_TBL22', DATE '2023-08-26',  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J66',   'ILLUM_STIG93',    DATE '2023-09-10', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J123',  'XYZ',             NULL,              99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J456',  'ABC',             TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 9, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J789',  'DEF',             TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 9, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| JOBID | JOBSPEC | TRIGDT | GAPDAYS | PRINTDT | COPYDT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J101 | PRINT_DOC164 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | 15 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | 2023-07-13 00:00:00 |
| J101 | PRINT_DOC164 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | 15 | 2023-07-14 00:00:00 | 2023-07-28 00:00:00 |
| J101 | PRINT_DOC164 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | 15 | 2023-07-29 00:00:00 | 2023-08-12 00:00:00 |
| J101 | PRINT_DOC164 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | 15 | 2023-08-13 00:00:00 | 2023-08-27 00:00:00 |
| J101 | PRINT_DOC164 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | 15 | 2023-08-28 00:00:00 | 2023-09-11 00:00:00 |
| J2213 | PRINT_SYS_TBL22 | 2023-08-26 00:00:00 | 9 | 2023-08-26 00:00:00 | 2023-09-03 00:00:00 |
| J2213 | PRINT_SYS_TBL22 | 2023-08-26 00:00:00 | 9 | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 | 2023-09-12 00:00:00 |
| J2213 | PRINT_SYS_TBL22 | 2023-08-26 00:00:00 | 9 | 2023-09-13 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 |
| J66 | ILLUM_STIG93 | 2023-09-10 00:00:00 | 11 | 2023-09-10 00:00:00 | 2023-09-20 00:00:00 |
| J789 | DEF | 2023-09-16 00:00:00 | 10 | 2023-09-16 00:00:00 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NvPKev7-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing yet another approach of solving the same problem. However, it doesn't match the expected output. The COPYDT in some rows are greater than SYSDATE.

Comment: @NiCKz Updated, just change the filter from `printdt` to `copydt` (and if you want to exclude the initial row then add a filter on the first part of the recursive query as well).

Comment: Thank you for your time and follow up answer :)